# Calculate hours between 22:00(today) and 06:00(tomorrow) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I want to calculate hours between 22:00(today) and 06:00(tomorrow) with javascript or jquery. If start time = 23:10 and stop time = 05:20
 working time to be 06:10, because from 23:10(today) to 05:20(tomorrow) there are 06:10 hours.

I have two input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="startTime" autocomplete="off" style="display:inline;width: 90px;" id="startTime" class="timepicker"/>

<input type="text" name="stopTime" autocomplete="off" style="display: inline;width: 90px;" id="stopTime" class="timepicker1"/>
```

My javascript code is:

```
var start_time = $('#startTime').val();
var end_time = $('#stopTime').val();


var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) / 60000 / 60;


var decimalTimeString = diff;
var n = new Date(0,0);
n.setSeconds(+decimalTimeString * 60 * 60);
var test = n.toTimeString().slice(0, 8);


$('#workingValue').val(test);
```

This javascript code works but only calculate hours between 00:00 to 23:45 e.g. if start time = 00:00 and stop time = 23:45 workingValue = 23:45 which is correct. But if start time is 22:00(for exampe) stop time is 01:00 my working value is not correct. It returning me 00:00 but has to be 03:00. Help me to resolve the problem please!
P.S. Sorry for my English, but it is not very good!

Comment: `It returning me 00:00` are you sure? I'd have thought it'd be negative ... check if `diff` is negative ... if so, add 24 to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - time counter since start date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049855/javascript-time-counter-since-start-date-and-time)

Comment: You can see the demo here. Mb hear you're answer - http://jsfiddle.net/c0rxkhyz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/)
in the snippet you can show an example

```js
let now  = "10/10/2018 15:00:00";
let then = "07/10/2018 14:20:30";

let ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
let d = moment.duration(ms);
let s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");

document.getElementById("time").innerText = s
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the information from your post, i.e. you only have two time strings without date information, you can do the following in Vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const ge=id=>document.getElementById(id);
const res=ge('result'), st=ge('start'), en=ge('end');
document.forms[0].addEventListener('keyup',function(el){
  res.innerHTML=new Date(new Date('1970-1-2 '+en.value)
                        -new Date('1970-1-1 '+st.value)).toGMTString().substr(17,5);
})
```

```html
<form>
<input id="start" value="22:30"> start<br>
<input id="end" value="2:00"> end<br>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate this calculation with *00:00* and *23:45* it gives **positive result** so okay but in opposite case let's say *23:45* *00:00* it will give **minus result**

```
var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) / 60000 / 60;
```